# trying to set up JSON file for languages to be translated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu, translation

I would like some help or advice in setting up my data.json file in the best way. I have it currently set up like the example below. The idea is I have a drop down menu that the use selects a language and I have say 50 pages, each page has the following format, I am trying to set it up so that the "house1" recognizes the locale language, and the "house2" is selectively translated via the option selected in the drop down menu. So the specific question I have here is How should I set up my data in the data.JSON so that when the selected language is called, the right id's are changed to the language selected.

```
<h1 id="house1"> House </h1>
<img src="~" />
<h1 id="house2"> House </h1>
```

//source code//

```
<select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="french">French</option>
  </select>
```

//data.json//

```
{
 "English":[
    {"Apartment": "Apartment"},
    {"House": "House"}
    ],

"French":[
    {"Apartment": "Appartement"},
    {"House": "Maison"}
    ]
}
```

or should I do something more like this: (the problem with this example to me is it looks cleaner but I can't figure out how I would differentiate each language to selectively call them)

```
{
 "Languages":[
    {"Apartment": "Apartment",
    "House": "House"},

    {"Apartment": "Appartement",
    "House": "Maison"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something on the html this:

```
<h1 id="selected.house"> House </h1>
<img src="~" />
<h1 id="available.house"> House </h1>
```

then the json structure:

```
{
 "selected":{
        "apartment": "Apartment",
        "house": "House"
    },

"available":{
    "apartment": "Appartement",
    "house": "Maison"
    }
}
```

if you need information abaout the selected language and the available on the json structure you can extend it like this:

```
{
 "selected":{
        "apartment": "Apartment",
        "house": "House",
        langInfo: {
            id: "en_EN",
            label: "English"
        }
    },

"available":{
    "apartment": "Appartement",
    "house": "Maison",
    langInfo: {
            id: "fr_FR",
            label: "French"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also look at [this](https://www.drzon.net/approaches-to-json-internationalisation-i18n/) and [this](http://i18njs.com/) as a source of inspiration.

Happy coding